# Only showing wifi networks with channel 11 (ralink)

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, arm, ralink

Im using an [ODroid wifi dongle](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G141630348024) (MediaTek(Ralink) RT5572N chipset) on a jetston TK1 ARM board. The dongle works fine on other machines but on the jetson, for some odd reason, it will only show (and connect to) wifi networks at channel 11 and nothing else.

iwlist / nmcli / wifi-radar only display the channel 11 networks even though there are other strong networks at lower and higher channels.

Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, uname:

```
Linux tegra-ubuntu 3.10.40-grinch-21.3.4 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri May 1 10:41:09 UTC 2015 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

dmesg output:

```
[ 5522.348831] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 31 using tegra-ehci
[ 5522.405935] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=5572
[ 5522.406154] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 5522.411722] usb 2-1.2: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
[ 5522.411816] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Ralink
[ 5522.411886] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 1.0
[ 5522.509661] usb 2-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 31 using tegra-ehci
[ 5522.553574] ieee80211 phy2: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 5592, rev 0222 detected
[ 5522.607281] ieee80211 phy2: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 000f detected
[ 5522.610789] ieee80211 phy2: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[ 5522.828157] ieee80211 phy2: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2870.bin'
[ 5522.829747] ieee80211 phy2: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.29
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 031: ID 148f:5572 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5572 Wireless Adapter
```

iw reg get:

```
country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
```

Channel list

```
$ iwlist wlan0 chan
wlan0     29 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 149 : 5.745 GHz
          Channel 151 : 5.755 GHz
          Channel 153 : 5.765 GHz
          Channel 155 : 5.775 GHz
          Channel 157 : 5.785 GHz
          Channel 159 : 5.795 GHz
          Channel 161 : 5.805 GHz
          Channel 165 : 5.825 GHz
```

Update: noticed that the very first time I run a scan on a fresh boot it shows all networks. Scanning after that very very sporadically shows all results, and then nothing again.

Added section of /var/log/syslog output below but not sure where else to look for logs.

```
Dec  6 23:17:41 tegra-ubuntu dbus[300]: [system] Successfully activated service 'fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1'
Dec  6 23:17:41 tegra-ubuntu NetworkManager[740]: <info> wpa_supplicant started
Dec  6 23:17:41 tegra-ubuntu wpa_supplicant[2461]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Dec  6 23:17:41 tegra-ubuntu NetworkManager[740]: <info> (wlan0) supports 4 scan SSIDs
Dec  6 23:17:41 tegra-ubuntu NetworkManager[740]: <warn> Trying to remove a non-existant call id.
Dec  6 23:17:41 tegra-ubuntu NetworkManager[740]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Dec  6 23:17:41 tegra-ubuntu NetworkManager[740]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
Dec  6 23:17:41 tegra-ubuntu NetworkManager[740]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: ready -> disconnected
Dec  6 23:17:41 tegra-ubuntu NetworkManager[740]: <info> (wlan0) supports 4 scan SSIDs
Dec  6 23:17:41 tegra-ubuntu wpa_supplicant[2462]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Dec  6 23:17:43 tegra-ubuntu ModemManager[630]: <warn>  Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/platform/tegra-ehci.2/usb2/2-1': not supported by any plugin
Dec  6 23:17:46 tegra-ubuntu NetworkManager[740]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
```

Comment: Is there any improvement if you set your regulatory domain? `sudo iw reg set IS` Of course, substitute your domain if not Iceland: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 After setting, scan again: `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately no change. Have added an update. Any suggestions where else to look?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually gave up and bought an intel 7260 mini PCI card. That works...